# CSS: Scale(x) makes icon rotate

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, pseudo-element

I have the following view icon for articles:

```css
.viewIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: #888;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 65% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 5px;
}

.viewIcon:before,
.viewIcon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.viewIcon:before {
    height: .5em;
    width: .5em;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: -.25em;
    margin-left: -.25em;
}

.viewIcon:after {
    height: .25em;
    width: .25em;
    background: #888;
    margin-top: -.1em;
    margin-left: -.11em;
}

.activeArticle {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="viewIcon"></div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="viewIcon activeArticle"></div>
```

As you can see the ".activeArticle" rotates the icon around 45 degrees.

1. Why is this happening? Am I missing something in the pseudo elements?
2. How can I fix it/How can I scale it without rotation? (transform/rotate will scale the icon back to the original size)

Comment: Have you tried rotate(0deg) ?

Comment: You reset transorm value. try:`.activeArticle {
    transform:rotate(45deg)  scale(1.5);}` transform can take more than 1 value.

Comment: You are overwriting your transform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are resetting your transform when you specify `scale` for `activeArticle` - use this:

```
.activeArticle {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.5);
}
```

Demo below:

```css
.viewIcon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: #888;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 65% 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 5px;
}
.viewIcon:before,
.viewIcon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.viewIcon:before {
  height: .5em;
  width: .5em;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -.25em;
  margin-left: -.25em;
}
.viewIcon:after {
  height: .25em;
  width: .25em;
  background: #888;
  margin-top: -.1em;
  margin-left: -.11em;
}
.activeArticle {
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="viewIcon"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="viewIcon activeArticle"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `rotate()` & `scale()` transform property combined, just like this:

```
.activeArticle {
  transform: scale(1.5) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```css
.viewIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: #888;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 65% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 5px;
}

.viewIcon:before,
.viewIcon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.viewIcon:before {
    height: .5em;
    width: .5em;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: -.25em;
    margin-left: -.25em;
}

.viewIcon:after {
    height: .25em;
    width: .25em;
    background: #888;
    margin-top: -.1em;
    margin-left: -.11em;
}

.activeArticle {
    transform: scale(1.5) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="viewIcon"></div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="viewIcon activeArticle"></div>
```

Hope this helps!